# Programmatically Connect + pairing doesn't always work for some of the android devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I am trying to achieve the following :

- Select a device from the scan results of BluetoothLeScan.
- Trying to connect to this device using BluetoothGatt.connect()
- Once the connection has been established, I try to createBond with the connected device as well.
- When this bond process is initiated I exchange the pin programmatically.
- Once this pin is exchanged with the peripheral device, I setPairingConfirmation(true) to dismiss the enter pin dialog.

***Problem*** - This doesn't work always. The pin isn't always exchanged successfully. Although the pin is written to the bluetooth stack successfully, but the pin received by the peripheral device is not the same. For some manufacturers like Samsung this problem has lower reproducibility but for others like iBall, this is 100% reproducible.

Please suggest

Comment: Can you post some details of the technologies and platforms you are using?

Comment: I am using an Android Tablet running on 4.4.2. We are trying to use Bluetooth LE to communicate with the peripheral device. We are really stuck on this problem, any help would be highly appreciated.